# ActiveRecord - querying polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I am using polymorphic associations to track Comments in my project. All very straight forward stuff.

The problem I have is in querying based on the polymorphic association and joining from the Comment model back to it's owner.

So ...

I have a Comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

And a ForumTopics mode:

```
class ForumTopic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

I have several other "commentable" models that aren't important right now. 
All of this works.

What I am trying to do is find all of the Comments that belong to a ForumTopic with a specified condition (in this case, 'featured' == true).

When I try and use a finder to join the models:

```
@comments = Comment.find(:all 
            :joins => :commentable
            :conditions => ["forum_topics.featured = ? ", true] 
            )
```

I receive the following error:

> *Can not eagerly load the polymorphic association :commentable*

Using the AR "include syntax":

```
@comments = Comment.find(:all 
            :include => :forum_topics
            :conditions => ["forum_topics.featured = ? ", true] 
            )
```

returns:

> *Association named 'forum_topics' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?*

If I try and join with a table name instead of the association name (string instead of symbol):

```
@comments = Comment.find(:all,
            :joins => "forum_topics",
            :conditions => ["forum_topics.featured = ? ", true] 
            )
```

I see:

> *Mysql::Error: Unknown table 'comments': SELECT comments.* FROM comments forum_topics WHERE (forum_topics.featured = 1 )*

(You can see here that the syntax of the underlying query is totally off and the join is missing altogether).

Not sure if what I am doing is even possible, and there are other ways to achieve the required result but it seems like it *should* be doable.

Any ideas?
Anything I am missing?

Comment: Oh, and I realise the conditions don't make so much sense ... but this was all originally in named_scopes and being passed parameters

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Argh!

I think I found the problem.

When joining via:

```
@comments = Comment.find(:all,
        :joins => "forum_topics",
        :conditions => ["forum_topics.featured = ? ", true] 
        )
```

You need the whole join!

```
:joins => "INNER JOIN forum_topics ON forum_topics.id = comments.commentable_id",
```

See the ever-awesome:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: Don't you hate it when the error is so mind-numblingly simple?

Comment: At least you posted the solution.  Kudos.

Comment: I think you also need to check that `comments.commentable_type` is the right type (in your case `"ForumTopic"`) otherwise you are doing a join with ALL the `comments.commentable_id` entries matching `forum_topics.id` even when they aren't forum topics.

Comment: @Jits can you clarify how you would alter the query to check for that?

Comment: Look at the answer by Chris barnes below for clarification on Jit's comment. Basically you would add a 'AND comments.commentable_type = "ForumTopic"'

Comment: This is not the correct answer. Watchout it will fail as soon as a comment is added to another Commentable polymorphic class that matches the same ID as a forum_topic

Answer (score 36):

An old question, but there is a cleaner way of achieving this by setting up a direct association for the specific type along with the polymorphic:

```
#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :forum_topics, -> { where( comments: { commentable_type: 'ForumTopic' } ).includes( :comments ) }, foreign_key: 'commentable_id'

  ...

end
```

You are then able to pass `:forum_topics` to `includes` getting rid of the need for a messy join:

```
@comments = Comment
  .includes( :forum_topics )
  .where( :forum_topics => { featured: true } )
```

You could then further clean this up by moving the query into a scope:

```
#comment.rb
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base

  ...

  scope :featured_topics, -> { 
    includes( :forum_topics )
    .where( :forum_topics => { featured: true } ) 
  }

  ...

end
```

Leaving you to be able to simply do

```
@comments = Comment.featured_topics
```

Comment: I tried exactly what you said, and it didn't work for me. https://gist.github.com/aruprakshit/edf202e12b073df838b0 . :/ No idea why.

Comment: @ArupRakshit, have you tried declaring your specific association as :review instead of :reviews? I think "belongs_to" should always be used with a singular relation name.

Comment: Scopes on the polymorphic model is definitely the cleanest way to go as it's DRY - the scopes can be used in controllers, views, etc while only being defined once in the model. In fact, that's probably why scopes were introduced in the first place!

Comment: I've just tried this on a Rails 5 project, and it does work, however I had to change the `includes(:forum_topics)` to `joins(:forum_topics)`, I think joins would have been better in the original answer to be honest. What problem are you running into?

Comment: What is the purpose of the join within the association scope? I don't see how this would return nil for a comment that actually does not belong to a forum topic. As a side note, it's somehow fundamentally wrong to declare a polymorphic association and then try to establish a direct connection to another model. This connection may not exist, that's why the polymorphic association is there in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't return nil for a comment not belonging to a forum topic, it simply doesn't return any comments not belonging to a forum topic. The join (the one back to comments I assume you mean?) is because the association is on forum_topics, it doesn't include comments by default. As for the legitimacy, the polymorphic relationship is saying the comment can belong to any model, but the association is just a convenience to say "give me all the forum topic comments".

Comment: To be fair, a polymorphic relationship is just a convenience and probably not 'best practice' as you can't enforce referential integrity at a database level. If you want to go for best practice I'd say you're better off with an intersection table (per associated model).

Comment: If this helps, it works for me in Rails 6, and I do not need to change to joins(:forum_topics). However, I have to use singular form `belongs_to :forum_topic, ...`

Answer (score 23):

### You Need a Conditional, Plus Rails 3+

A lot of people alluded to it in the answers and comments but I felt that people, including myself, would get tripped up if they landed here and didn't read thoroughly enough.

So, here's the proper answer, including the conditional that is **absolutely** necessary.

```
@comments = Comment.joins( "INNER JOIN forum_topics ON comments.commentable_id = forum_topics.id" )
                   .where( comments:     { commentable_type: 'ForumTopic' } )
                   .where( forum_topics: { featured:         true         } )
```

*Thanks to all, especially @Jits, @Peter, and @prograils for their comments.*

Comment: If you joins a `forum_topics`, why the `commentable_type` matters since it is the `forum_topics` type like you sad on `inner join`?

Comment: @WashingtonBotelho It matters because `Comment` is polymorphic and that `INNER JOIN` is only comparing the `id` of the `Comment` model. So, if `Comment` belongs to multiple models, like `ForumPost`, then that `INNER JOIN` will mistakenly include `Comment` records that belong to `ForumPost` as well.

Comment: This is by far the most informative answer on here and saved me hours of headache joining across multiple polymorphic associations. Thank you!

Comment: @Travis Thanks for the comment, Travis! Happy that it saved you time, that's what it's all about! :)

Comment: Doesn't work at least under Rails 5: no backticks are allowed here.

Comment: @prograils Our company isn't on Rails 5 yet. if you remove the back ticks in the SQL does it work?

Comment: @Josh Pinter Yes it does. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: @prograils I've updated the answer to include a section for Rails 5+ without the back ticks. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Really good explanation and great answer on the topic! Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

Checked to work under **Rails 5**:

**Solution 1:**

```
@comments = Comment
              .where(commentable_type: "ForumTopic")
              .joins("INNER JOIN forum_topics ON comments.commentable_id = forum_topics.id")
              .where(forum_topics: {featured: true})
              .all
```

or

**Solution 2:**

```
@comments = Comment
              .joins("INNER JOIN forum_topics ON comments.commentable_id = forum_topics.id AND comments.commentable_type = 'ForumTopic'")
              .where(forum_topics: {featured: true}).all
```

Pay attention to the raw SQL syntax: no backticks are allowed. See http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables .

I personally prefer Solution 1 as it contains fewer raw SQL syntax.

Answer (score 17):

The accepted solution does not work once you introduce another model that has an association using "commentable".  commentable_id is not unique and therefore you'll start retrieving the wrong comments.

For example:

You decide to add a news model that accepts comments...

```
class News < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end
```

Now you may get two records back if you made a comment on a forum_topic with an id of 1 and a news article with an id of 1 using your query:

```
:joins => "INNER JOIN forum_topics ON forum_topics.id = comments.commentable_id"
```

You could probably solve the problem by supplying a commentable_type as one of your conditions, but I don't think that's the best way to approach this issue.

Comment: Actually I think you're suggestion of supplying a commentable_type as one of the conditions is the right way to go... the [`act_as_taggable_on`](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) plugin does exactly that with their `taggings` table containing (amongst others) the columns: `tag_id`, `taggable_id` **and `taggable_type`**

Comment: This absolutely an astute observation. I've added an answer that prevents people from making this mistake like I did.

Answer (score 10):

I came across this post and it lead me to my solution.  Using the commentable_type as one of my conditions but using a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead.  That way forum topics without comments will be included.

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN `comments` ON `comments`.`commentable_id` = `forum_topics`.`id` AND `comments`.`commentable_type` = 'ForumTopic'
```

Comment: Doesn't work at least under Rails 5: no backticks are allowed here.

Comment: For the benefit of anyone finding the old above comment, the backticks are a MySQL thing, not a Rails thing. ANSI standard SQL would use double quotes, but in this case no quoting of the table/column names should be necessary, so you could just remove the backticks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to adapt to your purpose.

```
class AdwordsCampaign < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :daily_campaign_reports, as: :ga_campaign
end

class DailyCampaignReport < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :ga_campaign, polymorphic: true

  # scope
  def self.joins_ga_campaign(model)
    models = model.to_s.pluralize
    sql = <<~SQL
      INNER JOIN #{models}
      ON #{models}.id = daily_campaign_reports.ga_campaign_id
    SQL
    joins(sql).where(ga_campaign_type: model.to_s.camelize)
  end
end
```

Then I can use it wherever needed like this:

```
DailyCampaignReport.joins_ga_campaign(:adwords_campaign)
```

Answer (score 0):

Rails does not include a polymorphic join by default but this gem would help you to joins your polymorphic relationship with ease. https://github.com/jameshuynh/polymorphic_join