# Joins one way, but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-geocoder, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I can do this join:

```
User.joins(profile:[:address, :activity,:hobby])
```

However, I can not do this..

```
Address.joins(:profile)
```

I get:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Address' to association
>   named 'profile'; perhaps you misspelled it?)

so I have to do this..

```
Address.where(addressable_type: "Profile").joins("INNER JOIN profiles ON addresses.addressable_id = profiles.id").all
```

However, my preferred join would be to join everything from address so I can run geocoder gem .near() method.

```
Address.joins(profile:[:activity,:hobby,:user])
```

#### error:

> ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError (Can't join 'Address' to association
>   named 'profile'; perhaps you misspelled it?)

I need to join Address to Profile, and then Profile to activity, hobby and user.

### Models:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one  :address, as: :addressable
  has_one  :activity, as: :activityable
  has_one  :hobby, as: :hobbyable
end

class Address < ApplicationRecord
  geocoded_by :full_address
  after_validation :geocode, :if => :full_address

  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Activity < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activityable, polymorphic: true
end

class Hobby < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hobbyable, polymorphic: true
end
```

## schema

```
  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "user_id"
  end

  create_table "hobbies", force: :cascade do |t|

    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "hobbyable_type"
    t.bigint "hobbyable_id"
  end

  create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "business_street"
    t.string "business_city"
    t.string "business_state"
    t.string "business_country"
    t.string "business_postal_code"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "addressable_type"
    t.bigint "addressable_id"
    t.decimal "latitude", precision: 10, scale: 6
    t.decimal "longitude", precision: 10, scale: 6

  end

  create_table "activities", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "activityable_type"
    t.bigint "activityable_id"

  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "first_name"
    t.string "last_name"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

Comment: Is it possible to update the relationships section of the question to show the code relevant code from the models? It'll be easier to read that way, and might enable more insightful answers.

Comment: @SRack updated the models for you

Comment: I think you need the full join, check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/680141

Comment: you have to properly define the reverse polymorphic association to addressable. i'm not sure though if it's even supported from rails to do such a polymorphic join